# How to Solve "Trying to get property of non-object" in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-helper

If my code return null then it generates this error. If the code returns some data, then it works fine.

**Controller**

```php
$profile_data= DB::table('partner_prefence')
    ->select('*')
    ->where('profile_id',$profile_id)
    ->first();

return view('partner_prefence',['profile_data' =>  $profile_data]);
```

**View/Blade**

```
@php($rel_status = explode(',', $profile_data->p_marital_status))
```

If `$profile->p_marital_status` has a value then there's no issue. The error only comes when its value is null.

Comment: If you use `firstOrFail()` instead of `first()` it'll throw an error even before getting to the view, which you could catch and handle as required.

Comment: I am using first(), shouldI use firstorfail() ?

Comment: You don't *have* to... They both do the same thing essentially, but `firstOrFail()` will throw an error if no results are returned. You can use a `try ... catch` to handle that, or if you stick with `first()`, simply check `if($profile_data)` before passing it to the view. Ultimately it's up to you to figure out what to do if that data is `null`

Comment: I think you should follow the answer which has provided, because i think your view should show whether `profile_data` found or not.

Answer (score 3):

Use `optional()`
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-optional

If the given object is null, properties and methods will return null instead of causing an error.

```
{!! old('name', optional($user)->name) !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

First $profile_data need to be checked whether it is empty or it has some data.
step2: Checking $profile_data object has property called  p_material_status.
Step3: If the above both are true then try to explode the data otherwise return some error message and try not explode the data would be better.

```
<?php

$data = (($profile_data != null) && property_exists($profile_data->p_marital_status)) ? $profile_data->p_marital_status : null)
if($data){
$rel_status = explode(',', $data);
}else{
    // Something else
}

?>
```

Comment: When posting an answer, be sure to *explain* what's happening and why this answers the question; not all users will be able to infer this information and a short explanation goes a long way.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether the entry is vital for the page to be rendered or not, you could either perform a check in the controller.

```
$profile_data = DB::table('partner_prefence')
->select('*')
->where('profile_id',$profile_id)
->firstOrFail()
```

Or allow the null value to pass on to the view and make a ternary check.

```
$profile_data ? $profile_data->p_marital_status : '';
```

References:

[Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

[Retrieving Single Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use an `isset()` or `!= null` on the sentence like this:

```
@php($rel_status = $profile_data ? explode(',', $profile_data->p_marital_status?: '')) : [];
```